# How to synchronize a google calendar with google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-calendar-api

My goal is to synchronize a google calendar with a google spreadsheet automatically. Every time an event is added to the calendar, rows should be appended to the google spreadsheet. I wrote a script that loads the list of the upcoming event into a google spreadsheet.
This code is working and append the list of 10 events every time I run the script. However, what I want is to automatically run this script when an event is created via google calendar and I want to avoid duplicated events. What function is available for such event listener?

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
  var calendarId = 'alueducation.com_rtjgosrsgo9f4c6hqm5urebs68@group.calendar.google.com';
  var optionalArgs = {
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    showDeleted: false,
    singleEvents: true,
    maxResults: 10,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  };
  var response = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs);
  var events = response.items;
  if (events.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var event = events[i];
      var when = event.start.dateTime;
      if (!when) {
        when = event.start.date;
      }
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, when);
      addEventToSheet(event.summary, when);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No upcoming events found.');
  }
}
function addEventToSheet(sumarry, date) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([sumarry, date]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Use a time-drive trigger

## Explanation

At this time Google Apps Script is not able to bound a script to a Google Calendar. The alternatives are to use a bounded to a spreadsheet or a standalone script, so it's not possible at this time to trigger an script when an event is created in contrast with the form response submission.

## References

- [Types of Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)
- [Triggers and Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)